# jquery if anything in URL after specific page

Tags: javascript

I am looking to hide some items on a system where I have no control over the HTML.

I want to valid if there is anything after the url on the page of /jobs/. So for /jobs/ my function doesn't fire, the moment it becomes /jobs/XXXX then the function would fire.

I've tried this but I've no idea what it's actually doing as it validates on both /jobs/ and /jobs/xxx

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("jobs") != -1) {
   alert("your url contains the word jobs");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to detect if it explicitly **ends** in `/jobs/` with `$`

```
if((new RegExp('\/jobs\/$')).test(window.location.href)){
}
```

The reason

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("jobs") != -1) {
   alert("your url contains the word jobs");
}
```

was working regardless of whether it ended in `/jobs/` or not is because `indexOf()` checks that jobs exists **anywhere** in the string

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are only interested in the fact if URL ends with 'jobs/' or not. This is what you can do to check if it ends with 'jobs/' or not :

```
var str = window.location.href;

if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}

if(str.endsWith('jobs/'))
  console.log("Yes!"); //Do things here
else
  console.log("Nope"); // or here..
```